# Print value of an array or variable in a payment plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am programming a payment plugin for WooCommerce. For the purposes of testing it, I need to print the values of  `$response`.  I have tried this with`echo`, `print_r` and`var_dump`, but when I make the purchase process it does not print in any side.

**What can I do to visualize this content when buying a product?**
*(After entering the card details and making the purchase process I need to see those values)*

Part of the plugin code:

```
    $payload = array(
      "key_id"  => $key_id,
      "hash" => $hash,
      "time" => $time,
      "amount" => $customer_order->order_total,
      "ccnumber" => str_replace( array(' ', '-' ), '', $_POST['bac_payment-card-number'] ),
      "ccexp" => str_replace( array( '/', ' '), '', $_POST['bac_payment-card-expiry'] ),
      "orderid" => $orderid,
      "cvv" => ( isset( $_POST['bac_payment-card-cvc'] ) ) ? $_POST['bac_payment-card-cvc'] : '',
      "type" => "auth",);
    // Send this payload to Authorize.net for processing
    $response = wp_remote_post( $environment_url, array(
      'method'    => 'POST',
      'body'      => http_build_query( $payload ),
      'timeout'   => 90,
      'sslverify' => false,
    ) );

//***********
//when I make a purchase I need to see these values
//************
var_dump($response);
var_dump($response_body);

die()
```

Comment: [you can active debug log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and then save debug data in log with [error_log](http://php.net/error_log).

Answer (score 0):

Those are values you'll need to write to the log in order to view them.

In order to do that, make sure you've got debugging turned on in your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Then, use the following [utility function](https://wpbitz.com/utility-function-for-the-wordpress-error-log/) to write your values to the log.  You could just use `error_log( $value )`, bu this utility will handle dealing with arrays/objects without having to worry about formatting arrays for the log file:

```
function write_log( $log )  {
    if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
        error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
    } else {
        error_log( $log );
    }
}
```

Now instead of `var_dump()`, you can call `write_log()` to dump your result to /wp-content/error.log:

```
write_log($response);
write_log($response_body);
```

([There was a similar type of question yesterday](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/353865/wp-mail-not-running-inside-cron), if you want to see some additional detail.)